# wcf async callback throws tcp exception

Tags: c#, wcf

I've implemented client-server application via tcp. I am using async pattern because I'm limited to .NET 3.5. In this case, I'm forced to use ChannelFactory in order to communicate between client and server, no code generation. This simple app is based on a simple MSDN wcf async example (no client code though). Service is hosted in a windows service. When I call Begin method, everything works fine, but when I try to get the result from the End method in callback, I get the TCP error 10061 : "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it...". Contracts are held in separate DLL which is included in service implementation DLL and client DLL. Config file is the same for both service and windows service.

This is my Contract

```
[ServiceContractAttribute]
public interface ISampleService
{
    [OperationContractAttribute]
    string SampleMethod(string msg);

    [OperationContractAttribute(AsyncPattern = true)]
    IAsyncResult BeginSampleMethod(string msg, AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState);

    string EndSampleMethod(IAsyncResult result);
}
```

IAsyncResult implementation:

```
public class CompletedAsyncResult<T> : IAsyncResult
{
    T data;

    public CompletedAsyncResult(T data)
    { this.data = data; }

    public T Data
    { get { return data; } }

    #region IAsyncResult Members
    public object AsyncState
    { get { return (object)data; } }

    public WaitHandle AsyncWaitHandle
    { get { throw new Exception("The method or operation is not implemented."); } }

    public bool CompletedSynchronously
    { get { return true; } }

    public bool IsCompleted
    { get { return true; } }
    #endregion
}
```

Service Implementation:

```
public class SampleService : ISampleService
{
    public string SampleMethod(string msg)
    {
        return "sync " + msg;
    }

    // This asynchronously implemented operation is never called because 
    // there is a synchronous version of the same method.
    public IAsyncResult BeginSampleMethod(string msg, AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("BeginSampleMethod called with: " + msg);
        return new CompletedAsyncResult<string>(msg);
    }

    public string EndSampleMethod(IAsyncResult r)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        CompletedAsyncResult<string> result = r as CompletedAsyncResult<string>;
        Console.WriteLine("EndSampleMethod called with: " + result.Data);
        return result.Data + " after processing";
    }
}
```

Service config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>

        <binding name="TcpUnsecured">
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                        enabled="false" />
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Cube.Service1Behavior" name="Cube.ISampleService">
        <clear />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" listenUriMode="Explicit">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
            <certificateReference storeName="My" storeLocation="LocalMachine"
              x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://DavePC:1430/Test" 
                  binding="netTcpBinding" 
                  bindingConfiguration="TcpUnsecured"
                  name="tcp" 
                  contract="ns.ISampleService" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://DavePC:1430/Test" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Cube.Service1Behavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Client implementation:

```
public delegate void AsyncSampleAction(string result, ISampleService c);
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestMSDNAsyncWCF();
    }

    private static void TestMSDNAsyncWCF()
    {
         ISampleService channel = GetChannelSampleService();

        IAsyncResult result = channel.BeginSampleMethod("FINALLY ASYNC", FinishSampleAction, channel);

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue . . .");
        Console.ReadKey(false);
    }

    static void FinishSampleAction(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        var state = (ISampleService) ar.AsyncState;
        string msg = state.EndSampleMethod(ar);
        Console.WriteLine(msg);
    }

    private static ISampleService GetChannelSampleService()
    {
        ChannelFactory<ISampleService> factory = null;
        factory = new ChannelFactory<ISampleService>("tcp");
        ISampleService channel = factory.CreateChannel();
        return channel;
    }
}
```

Client config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>

        <binding name="TcpUnsecured">
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                        enabled="false" />
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Cube.Service1Behavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <client>
      <endpoint name="tcp"
                address="net.tcp://DavePC:1430/Test"
                contract="ns.ISampleService"
                binding="netTcpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="TcpUnsecured" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I know that this was lengthy but I just can't see the solution right now.

Comment: I think the problem is your "channel" variable is going out of scope and closing the connection,this would explain why FinishSampleAction is never called, however I am not sure what you mean by "try to get the result from the End method in callback", or where the error is happening.